# Change the timezone configuration for particular timezone

Tags: php, linux, timezone

Assuming i have full access to the server (SSH, FTP etc.) what is the best way to change the timezone values for the particular timezone (i.e. for Russia/Moscow)?

I've tried installing the pecl timezonedb, it did install, i added it in php.ini, did full reboot and still nothing.. (phpinfo shows old 2007.* version of the timezonedb)

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Comment: you want the timezone for the computer or for the user on your website as you have php as tag in your question

Answer (score 0):

Changing a time zone involves downloading the [timezone database source files](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), changing the rules in one of the files, and recompiling them using `zic`. Then you would probably want to override the system-installed version in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` with your own.

Why do you want to change one of the timezones? Is it because the rules are incorrect. If so, you should consider reporting the problem on the [mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/mailman/listinfo/tz). The master database will be corrected and a new version will be published. They accept patches to the database even for something minor like an incorrect historical daylight savings time rule.

If you just want to use a custom UTC offset plus (optionally) a simple daylight savings time rule, you might also consider using a custom `TZ` environment variable instead of a predefined time zone, using the [standard POSIX syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html).